# error al tratar de mostrar cual es mayor o menor con def

Tags: python-3.x

hola como pueden ver estoy aprendiendo python y ps voy por funciones y ps quise en un esta primera funcion guaradar  este pequeño codigo que por entrada de pantalla pidiera dos numeros y se guardara en la variable n3 como resultado final

```
def hola():
    n1 = float(input("ingrese el primer numero: "))
    n2 = float(input("ingrese el segundo numero: "))
    n3 = n1+n2
```

en el siguiente código  utiliza un if para decirle al programa que numero era mayor o menor

```
if 10 > hola():
    print("10 es mayor ")
else:
    print(hola() ,"es mayor")
```

respectivamente ps le doy ejecutar y me pide los dos números pero despues de ingresarlos me sale el siguiente error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-e64385464eee> in <module>
----> 1 if 10 > hola():
      2     print("10 es mayor ")
      3 else:
      4     print(hola() ,"es mayor")

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Estás comparando 10 con el resultado _retornado_ por `hola()`, pero esa función no retorna nada. Simplemente calcula una suma y la guarda en `n3`, pero no retorna ese resultado. Debes añadirle `return n3`. Por otro lado, no quieres volver a llamarla cuando vayas a imprimir si es mayor (porque entonces te volvería a pedir los datos). Mejor la llamas una sola vez antes del `if`, guardas en otra variable el valor retornado y luego en el `if` usas esa variable en vez de `hola()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Por qué no mejor dejar la lógica del `if` dentro de la misma función?

Digo que la función procese por dentro primero la suma que se almacena en `n3` y dicha variable sirva para compararla dentro del condicional simple; quedando así

```
def hola():
    n1 = float(input("ingrese el primer numero: "))
    n2 = float(input("ingrese el segundo numero: "))
    n3 = n1+n2

    if 10 > n3:
      print("10 es mayor ")
    else:
      print(n3 ,"es mayor")


hola()
```

Resultando esto

> Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux
>   ingrese el primer numero: 8 ingrese el segundo numero: 5
>   13.0 es mayor

O también puedes igualar el método `hola()` a alguna variable; en este caso número quedando así

```
def hola():
    n1 = float(input("ingrese el primer numero: "))
    n2 = float(input("ingrese el segundo numero: "))
    n3 = n1+n2
    return n3

numero = hola()

if 10 > numero:
    print("10 es mayor ")
else:
    print(numero ,"es mayor")
```

[Enlace al ejemplo](https://repl.it/repls/PassionateBuoyantEmulators)